Saving my resistor
Does it matter if you put 2 different resistors in parallel and how would you keep the lower rated resistor safe if you know the power output is greater than resistor can handle?
Edit: I'm using 2 variable resistors. 1 rated for .25w per (the right word is slipping my mind but it's when you adjust the knob) and the other is a 25w rating per (same denominator as the last) I'm trying to create a .1 ohm 50w resistor. I have 2 of each. Is it possible?
PS. I'm not an engineer :] just a guy trying not to start a fire ya know.

Please describe what you are trying to do, including a schematic.

As often happens on this site, the question is clear in your head, but not in ours.

If the power in a resistor is greater than that resistor can handle, it will blow, changing the circuit, which in turn can lead to more things blowing.

You can put resistors of different resistance and/or power specifications in parallel.  I frequently do this so I can get ~1% values with two 5% resistors.  However, if one is much larger than the other (>10X) the smaller one and its tolerance will dominate the resulting value as well as bearing the lion's share of the power dissipation.
If you're doing it for the purpose of improving the power dissipation, you want to balance it among several devices of substantially the same value.  You can use N resistors of value NR in parallel to get a total resistance of R.  Similarly, you can replace R with N resistors of value R/N in series.  You want to make sure they're all not twisted together in a tight bunch, or the power dissipation of each one (especially the ones in the middle) will be derated.

Then you are assuming the 5% resistors maintain their value within 1% over time? (Which probably is true, after all the 1% types are usually just selected from the same product line. But strictly speaking it is not guaranteed...)

I mainly use the technique for prototypes, because while we only have 5% resistors in the lab reliably, our CM stocks most 1% values.  Also, for prototypes, you can check the initial value with a meter, and they don't change much in a couple weeks.  (If you use this in production, you'd have to sort them yourself; most of the good ones are within 1% anyway, but they're only guaranteed to 5%.)

Ignoring derating for now.
Example: If you wanted 9 ohms and put 10 ohms and 100 ohms in parallel. If the voltage is 10 volts, the total power dissipated will be 11 Watts. But you can't use two 6 Watt resistors, the power isn't shared equally. Calculate each separately, the voltage is the same since they are in parallel.
\$ P = \frac{V^2}{R} \$
\$ P = \frac{10^2}{10} = 10W \$
\$ P = \frac{10^2}{100} = 1W \$
Now add derating. If the resistors are at room temperature, I recommend at least 50% derating. So, 20W and 2W resistors.
